# EF Code First ignore Property to Field Convention?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, conventions

Is there a way to then ignore the conventions completely, so that Code First doesn't try to map any properties to database fields at all automatically, and I just define my own mapping completely manually on my own?

Comment: Check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370518/ef-4-1-code-first-is-there-an-easy-way-to-remove-all-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog which explains how to remove all conventions. it will work for upcoming versions too.
http://blog.cincura.net/232283-removing-all-conventions-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I had already tried this. It doesn't remove assuming that each property is mapped to a table field.