# Invalid column name error although it exists ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, sql-server-2008

I am designing an online store (ASP.NET Core 6) for an accounting software (C# Winforms).

I started this using ASP.NET Core and Razor pages.

I am new and inexperienced in this field. The accounting software has many tables in SQL Server, and these tables are related to each other.
I try to make model only the tables I need for my project.

But when communicating with the desired table, get the following error :( .

> Invalid column name 'MobileNo'.
> Invalid column name 'BankAccountNumber'.
> Invalid column name 'BankBranch'.
> Invalid column name 'BirthDate'.
> Invalid column name 'BrithLocation'.
> ....

I know that this error is due to the relationships of the desired table with other tables.

Because in other similar cases, when I defined the second table and the relationship, this error was resolved.

```
....
public string UserID { get; set; }
....
[ForeignKey(nameof(UserID))]
public virtual SalCustomer users { get; set; }
....
```

but I came across a table that is very related to other tables (tables that are not needed).

I feel it is not right to create extra models and I don't like to add them to my project.

Is there a way in EF to ignore relationships? Without causing a problem in the accounting software?

Because there is no need for these relationships in my project.

For example:

the relationship between the customer table and the tax document table or the Cheque table and... there are too many tables.

Is it better to create all the tables in my project even though I don't need them?

An example of the code that generates this error.

```
var accPerson = _context.AccPerson.SingleOrDefault(c => c.mobileNo == SD.userPh1);
```

I apologize for my terrible English and thank you in advance for your valuable comments.

i read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370518/ef-4-1-code-first-is-there-an-easy-way-to-remove-all-conventions/5370878#5370878)
but i think that the relationships will be completely removed and this may cause problems in the accounting software.
I can't make any changes to the database.
Because many companies and software are using this database.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support over **4 years ago**; it is long past time you implemented your (presumably for some time) finalised upgrade plan.

Comment: @ThomA The main accounting software uses 2008, and the database was originally designed with it, but I restored a backup of the database to SQL Server 2022 for my project... That's why the place that has both face-to-face and online sales uses the database from SQL Server 2022.
In any case, this does not seem to have anything to do with the current problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using Ef core database first approach, you can specify the tables that you want to generate.

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Connection string' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables Customer, Purchases, Accounts, Contracts
```

[more information on scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=vs)

If you want more control you can learn how T4 templates work (might be a bit complicated if you are a beginner)

[Using T4 templates for reverse engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#introduction-to-t4)

Comment: Thank you for your comment , 
But I don't want to create a table or anything , I just want relationships to be ignored , 
I think there should be a attribute like a [NotMapped] or ...

Comment: You don't have to create any tables. When following the code first approach, EF will only add the tables that you have mentioned in the command and will only generate the relations for those tables. So, you don't have to worry about the tables that you won't use. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The right choice could be to create an EF Project **Database first**. Visual Studio will generate the models for You. Because You cannot update database rows ignoring relationships: which values would You put in foreign keys properties?

Comment: I created the models manually, almost similar to the database first  model , even defined only the required columns :)
And I never use migration (I can't use it) because the smallest change in the database can cause many problems.
Before this incident, tables that are related were needed and I used to model them as well.
I still don't know if I started the right thing or not
We have 114 tables of which only 22 are needed